# Git bypass conflict that is caused by editing different lines

Tags: bash, git

I have parallel automation scripts running that change different lines in one file and commit it. Because there might be race conditions each script will try to pull changes if push fails because another script has probably edited it meanwhile:

```
while ! git push; do git pull; done
```

And this seems to work most of the time. I see that sometimes push fails, the pull is done successfully and then push is done again.
But some times It fails with a conflict during pull:

```
 Auto-merging FILE
 CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in FILE
 Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

To me it seems that the conflict will happen if the changed lines are next to each other. Is it somehow possible to bypass this conflict if i know for certain that every script has its own line that it edits and no actual conflict happens.

Answer (score 0):

Git will indeed cause a merge conflict if two adjacent lines are changed.  That's to avoid surprises when nearby lines change, as outlined in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/why-doesnt-git-merge-adjacent-lines-without-conflict).  This is not configurable with the default merge strategies, but you could use a custom merge strategy to avoid it (which would be nontrivial to implement).

As a note, if you're using automation to change files in a repository like this, it might be worth considering whether those files should be stored in a Git repository in the first place.  Usually any sort of data file doesn't belong in a repository and should be stored elsewhere.